# Django rest framework - use serializer create method or api perform_create for account register

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create an endpoint for creating a new user. If I put a create method in the serializer will perform_create still be called on my ApiView? It seems User.objects.create is still being called because if I pass 'confirm-password' in the serializer I get an error:

> Got a `TypeError` when calling `User.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `User.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the UserSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.
>   Original exception text was: 'confirm_password' is an invalid keyword argument for this function.

Why is User.objects.create() being called when I'm using .create_user() in the serializer create method? This is also causing is_active to default to true even though I'm setting it to false in the serializer.

```
class UserCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)
    confirm_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'username',
              'first_name', 'last_name', 'password',
              )
        read_only_fields = ('date_joined')

    def validate_email(self, value):

        if value and User.objects.filter(email=value).count():
            raise serializers.ValidationError(u'Email addresses is already registered.')
        return value

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            email=validated_data['email'],
            password=validated_data['password'],
            is_active=False)
        return user


class UserCreateApiView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny,]
    queryset = get_user_model().objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, `User.objects.create_user()` will always result in a user where `is_active` is True.

> #### [create_user(username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user)
>
> Creates, saves and returns a User.
>
> The username and password are set as given. The domain portion of
>   email is automatically converted to lowercase, and the returned User
>   object will have is_active set to True.
>
> If no password is provided, set_unusable_password() will be called.
>
> The extra_fields keyword arguments are passed through to the User’s
>   __init__ method to allow setting arbitrary fields on a custom User model.

Here's a possible workaround:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
        username=validated_data['username'],
        email=validated_data['email'],
        password=validated_data['password'])

    user.is_active = False
    user.save()
    return user
```

Comment: Is that true for 1.9? I should say that I can use create_user from the console and pass is_admin=False and it works as expected. https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py

Comment: But if you are passing in is_active=False to create_user it sets is_active to False as expected. I just tested this in the console again to be sure.

Comment: I copied your create method to my serializer and it still fails so drf is saving the user object in some other way that I don't quite understand.

Comment: Maybe because your API view users a serializer called UserSerializer instead if UserCreateSerializer?

Comment: I should have edited that but I didnt catch it before posting. The UserCreateSerializer and UserSerializer are the same though. I'm assuming the CreateAPIView is calling user.objects.create and ignoring my create method in the serializer.

Comment: Try debugging it with a line debugger such as `pdb`.